# PickerIOS not working with React Native

Tags: react-native, reactjs

I have a component that I am trying to render a list of values through the PickerIOS react native component but the items are not populating. I want to populate the jobs.type values.

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react-native'
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient'
import {List} from 'immutable'

const {
  Image,
  View,
  ListView,
  MapView,
  PickerIOS,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
} = React;

let PickerItemIOS = PickerIOS.Item;
import {changePage} from '../actions/PageActions'
import {dashboardStyle, style} from '../styles'

class JobsMap extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const region = {
      latitude: 42.333390,
      longitude: -71.083523,
      latitudeDelta: .01,
      longitudeDelta: .01,
    }

    const annotations = this.props.jobs.map((job) => ({
      latitude: job.location[0],
      longitude: job.location[1],
      title: job.title,
      subtitle: job.type,
      id: job.title
    })).toJS()

    console.log(annotations)

    return <MapView
            onAnnotationPress={(x) => console.log(x)}
            annotations={annotations}
            region={region}
            style={dashboardStyle.map} />
  }
}


export default class EmployerDashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {jobType: 'Server'};

    const datasource = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1.title !== r2.title && r1.badge !== r2.badge
    })

    const jobs = List([{
      title: "A restaurant",
      type: "Server",
      location: [42.33, -71.08],
    }, {
      title: "Some place nice",
      type: "Server",
      location: [42.333390, -71.083523],
    }, {
      title: "Happy meals",
      type: "Server",
      location: [42.335, -71.079],
    }, {
      title: "Cool Cafe",
      type: "Bartender",
      location: [42.337, -71.08],
    }])

    this.state = {datasource, jobs}
    this.state.datasource = this.updateDatasource()
  }

  updateDatasource() {
    const xs = this.state.jobs
    .groupBy(thing => thing.type)
    .map(x => x.size)
    .entrySeq().map((x) => ({
      title: x[0],
      badge: x[1]
    })).toJS()

    return this.state.datasource.cloneWithRows(xs)
  }

  renderSeparator() {
    return <View style={dashboardStyle.rowSeparator} />
  }

  render() {
    //const toolong = "https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/10848063_889114987800263_2854852205112396164_n.jpg?oh=6eb110dc1c6d722f989bf0f0431c8a7d&oe=565139C3"
    //const avauri = {uri: toolong}
    const avauri = {uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}
    const {datasource, jobs} = this.state

    return (
      <View style={style.view}>
        <View style={dashboardStyle.info}>
          <PickerIOS
            selectedValue={this.state.jobType}
              onValueChange={(jobType) => this.setState({jobType})}>
              {Object.keys(jobs).map((jobType) => (
                <PickerItemIOS
                  key={jobType}
                  value={jobType}
                  label={jobs.name}
                 />
                )
              )}
          </PickerIOS>
        </View>
        <JobsMap jobs={jobs} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using List from Immutable the jobs "List" works a bit different. There are a few mistakes in the following code:

```
{Object.keys(jobs).map((jobType) => (
        <PickerItemIOS
            key={jobType}
            value={jobType}
            label={jobs.name}
        />
    )
)}
```

1. Object.keys gives you the properties of jobs which is an instance of the class List. So, you're iterating over the properties with .map()
2. What did you expect jobs.name to be? Why like that?

## Solution

In general, try to understand how Immutable works. You can iterate over your List this way:

```
{jobs.map((job, index) => (
    <PickerItemIOS
        key={index}
        value={index}
        label={job.type}
    />
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<View>
    <PickerIOS style={styles.picker}>
        {(this.state.people).map((person, index) =>
        <PickerItemIOS
            key={index}
            value={person.name}
            label={person.name}
        />
        )}
    </PickerIOS>
</View>
```

I was able to make this to work. Hope this helps